# How to read Jquery Version from Chrome browser console for webpages and write in eclipse Java console through selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, jsoup

How to read Jquery Version from Chrome browser console for webpages and write in eclipse Java console through selenium.

Command: $. ui. version

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following commands within the console:

- *`$().jquery;`*
- *`$.fn.jquery`*

Snapshot:

[image: jQuery_version]

---

### Programmatically

To redirect the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) version within the browser console you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://jquery.com/")
  print(driver.execute_script("return $().jquery;"))
  print(driver.execute_script("return $.fn.jquery"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  1.11.3
  1.11.3
  ```